# Insert query is not working! The values are not being reflected on the table

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to register a user in my react-native application. When i press the signup button, the values are not updated in the database. The tables are empty. There doesn't seem to be any error that is being displayed.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql =  require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database:'SampleDb',
})


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var phone = req.body.phone;

  connection.query("INSERT INTO reg (id,name,email,password,phone) VALUES (null,'?', '?', '?','?')"),[name,email,password,phone];
});
module.exports = router;
```

This is my react native code

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name:'',
            email:'',
            password:'',
            phone:'',
            }

        };
     Reg = () => {
            fetch('http://192.168.0.20:3000/UserReg', {
             method : 'POST',
                  headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                  },

                  body: JSON.stringify({
                  email:this.state.email,
                  name:this.state.name,
                  password:this.state.password,
                  phone:this.state.phone,

                  })
            })

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                  if(res.success=== true){
                  var email = res.message;

                     AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email);
                     Actions.Ideas();}
                     else {
                    alert(res.message);
                }
```

The query for seems to be working fine. I don't understand the problem. Please help.

Comment: You have a typo on your query : `connection.query("INSERT INTO reg (id,name,email,password,phone) VALUES (null,'?', '?', '?','?')"),[name,email,password,phone];` ==> `connection.query("INSERT INTO reg (id,name,email,password,phone) VALUES (null,'?', '?', '?','?')",[name,email,password,phone])`;
I'd also add a function to see if the query performed successfully: `connection.query("INSERT INTO ...", [...], function(err, results) {...})`

Comment: Are you receiving the alert message from your `alert(res.message);` statement?

Comment: I don't use node.js or react at all, so I'm not too sure on the syntax, however normally you wouldn't put quotes around the question marks in your SQL query when using prepared statements. So the query would become `INSERT INTO reg (id,name,email,password,phone) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: @G.Hamaide even after adding the function. It is not working.

Comment: @David R, i haven't passed any message yet. so no messages are being displayed.

Comment: @AvikritKhati is the function returning an error ? If yes, this might give you hints on why it is not working

Comment: Nope, it just goes straight to the page that is supposed to go to.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO reg (id,name,email,password,phone)
VALUES (null,'?', '?', '?','?')"),[name,email,password,phone];
```

Try to fire commit command.